# find points on arc for shortest distance between two locations

Tags: wgs84, great-circle

I have two points on the earth.  The shortest path between these two points forms an arc. **How do I find the points that represent this arc?** Bonus points if you can help with an answer in regards to an ellipsoid (WGS84).

Comment: What software are you using? For ArcGIS something like this sounds like it does what you need (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/generate-points-along-lines.htm) but maybe you can clarify what your end result looks like and what you have tried already?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm limited to what is available in boost.  There is limited GIS support in boost so I'll most likely need to implement this by hand.  I think https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_navigation has my answer but I'm confused on what numbers to plug in where